# Using StepVerifier in a parallel testing environment

Tags: project-reactor

I am having some trouble when using StepVerifier's `withVirtualTime` and `create` methods in a parallel testing environment.

```
private static final Duration DELAY = Duration.ofSeconds(1);

public void testA() {
    StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(() -> Mono.just(1).delayElement(DELAY))
            .thenAwait(DELAY)
            .expectNext(1)
            .expectComplete()
            .verify();
}

public void testB() {
    StepVerifier.create(Mono.just(1).delayElement(DELAY))
            .thenAwait(DELAY)
            .expectNext(1)
            .expectComplete()
            .verify();
}
```

Maven Surefire plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <groups>unit</groups>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
        </includes>
        <parallel>methods</parallel>
        <threadCount>2</threadCount>
        <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

These tests fail with the following exceptions (The full stack traces available on GitHub, please refer links below.):

```
[ERROR] testA(com.github.hisener.StepVerifierTest)  Time elapsed: 0.04 s  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException: timedScheduler
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:246)
[ERROR] testB(com.github.hisener.StepVerifierTest)  Time elapsed: 0.043 s  <<< FAILURE!
reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactorRejectedExecutionException: Scheduler unavailable
    at reactor.core.Exceptions.failWithRejected(Exceptions.java:249)
```

I don't think it's related to `delayElements`, for instance, one of the following tests uses `timeout` and they also fail:

```
public void testA() {
    StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(() -> Mono.just(1)).expectNext(1).expectComplete().verify();
}

public void testB() {
    StepVerifier.create(Mono.just(1).timeout(DELAY)).expectNext(1).expectComplete().verify();
}
```

I have tested on both TestNG and Junit 5, but no luck. The code is available on GitHub:

- TestNG https://github.com/hisener/reactor-test-test
- JUnit 5 https://github.com/hisener/reactor-test-test/tree/junit5

Answer (score 0):

`StepVerifier#withVirtualTime` replaces ALL default Schedulers with the virtual time one, so it is not a good idea to use it in parallel

Comment: Do you recommend using `StepVerifier#withVirtualTime` instead of `StepVerifier#create` while testing a publisher that depends on a specific `Scheduler` (ie; `timeout`, `delayElement` or `subscribeOn(...)`)? It's going to be serial because of mutex lock but at least it's safer, I guess?

Comment: yeah that would probably be safer